How to run a heater vent down through a top plate
We have a single gas heater with no heat distribution at the front of our first floor, and that generally means the back of our first floor is fairly cold.
We have a crawl space above our first floor with plenty of space to run ducting.
So my plan was to put an exhaust fan above the heater that goes into a duct to drive the heat through an insulated duct and then have it drop down the wall in our back room so we can have the heat coming out of a vent near the floor.
Unfortunately I now see that the walls I would want to drop through have a top plate that I'd have to open up.  Fortunately the wall is 7" deep, my guess is it was once the back of the house - and the top plate is actually two 2x4s.  The top plate was likely added when the crawl space was added, since the crawl space was actually created when the ceiling was dropped.
My first guess is that I can take out the top plate between the last two studs in the wall, as long as I tie them in well enough to the floor joists of the crawl space that they are in between, but I'm open to other suggestions (or feedback that my entire plan is a bad idea).
Best way to accomplish this goal?

Your question is unanswerable without more contextual information or photos. A wall plate serves several potential roles depending on what's happening around it. No one's going to say "sure, cut it out!" without seeing that entire area.
